# Laravel 5.3 and VueJS 2 Authenticating

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2

Im using Laravels default auth to lock down some paths in the routes/api.php file.

```
Route::get('/projects', 'ProjectController@index')->middleware('auth:api');
```

I log the user in via a PHP form (not via a http request via Vue).
This creates the session and when I submit a HTTP request via Vue I can see that the header includes the Cookie and X-CSRF-Token however I keep getting a 401 `{"error":"Unauthenticated."}`

In my config/auth I have api driver set as 'token' (have tried changing this to 'session' but that did work :/)

From my understanding and what I have read online I should be able to use the default Laravel auth functionality to accomplish API calls from Vue HTTP requests.

```
this.$http.get('/api/projects')
   .then(response => {
     this.projects = response.body;
   })
   .catch (err => {
     console.log(err);
   });
```

I've read about methods of authenticating by generating an JWT token and storing that in local storage when the user logs in. Is this the method I should use or should I be able to accomplish it with the default Laravel Auth middleware?

Hope my questions make sense, any help/advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `auth:api` middleware doesn't use cookies, it uses `api_token` param, which can be passed via `get` or `Bearer <token>` header. Just use `web` middleware.

I suppose you need to access the same route in two ways - for API users and  for browser users. So why don't you create two routes for one action?

```
// api group with /api prefix
Route::get('/projects', 'ProjectController@index')->middleware('auth:api');

// web group 
Route::get('/projects', 'ProjectController@index')->middleware('web');
```

Comment: Thanks @shukshin.ivan looks like I was just overcomplicating things. As the user will be authenticating via PHP and setting a session, I have grouped my "API calls" in the web routes. If I need to access the API from an external source I'll use the auth:api and token method.